# confusion on "quality of + verb form"

Tags: phrase-usage, noun-phrases

I have some confusion about the `quality of +  verb form`. I have two sample sentences

> 1. The quality of their clothing is very good.
> 2. It really improves my overall quality of sleep.

My question is why can not it be `Quality of their clothes` and `quality of sleeping?`

When should I use "quality of+verb"?

When should I use "quality of + verb+ing"?

Comment: It's usually [*the quality of life*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+quality+of+life%2Cthe+quality+of+living&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20quality%20of%20life%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20quality%20of%20living%3B%2Cc0) or [*the standard of living*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+standard+of+life%2Cthe+standard+of+living&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20standard%20of%20life%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20standard%20of%20living%3B%2Cc0), not the other way around.

Comment: (The former is often more about "intangibles" such as happiness, security, satisfaction, whereas the latter is more likely to be about *having plenty of money*, and such things as can be "bought".)

Comment: I edited my question. Now the question is alright.

Comment: There's nothing particularly "unusual" about references to the quality of someone's clothes. But it *just so happens* that ***idiomatically*** we usually talk about *quality of sleep* rather than *...sleeping*. And even though we'd usually want to [*improve the eating quality*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22improve+the+eating+quality%22) of some foodstuff, there's nothing wrong with trying to [*improve the quality of eating*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22improve+the+quality+of+eating%22) of/for it.

Comment: Can anyone give any examples at all where the participle form is the common use?

Comment: @BadZen  Your question shows quality breeding. It provided quality reading. I will now celebrate at a 5 star restaurant where I expect quality dinning. I will travel on a properly constructed roadway that provides quality driving.

Comment: @puppetsock - The form suggested was "quality of" + participle.   Of course you can use "quality" without the proposition as an adjective in front of a gerund, and that's very common use!

Comment: Isn't clothing a noun? In this context isn't sleep a noun?